# diference between preview and render

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, light, glass

[image]

Hello

i ma a bit noob... but i need to make glass for helmet which i will put on someone face after that...

so i would like to have the same resoluts with preview render and final render.

so please can someone help me to have the sam resoluts in preview like in render ? thanks

it happend just when i do that glass transparent for render (so that mabie happend in old version too i am not sure now)

here is non transparent shoot:[image]

Comment: is there a subsurf modifier on your model, the lower render doesn't support this, but is there anything different between preview and render settigns?

Comment: it was... but not any more... - and still the same resolut

Comment: can i send you that file ? i do not know where are some preview render settings ...

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PSOeJB4dgv130vQRj1NtwlUuWvJRAq3-/view?usp=sharing

Comment: for now i helped it with higher IOR... but that is not at all the solution :( -> this is reason why i lefted cinema 4D 7 years ago.. becouse theyer preview render was so diferent to final render...

Answer (score -1):

I found a solution: You can refine the alpha channel post render, here is how:
[image]

Just use any node that can influence a gradient and stick it in between the native alpha channel and the one of the output node.

Comment: Could someone elaborate why this answer is unhelpful?

Comment: this is not rly the solution... this solution at the end looks even more diferent than actual glass from shaders... but thanks... i get better resolut with that diferent IOR.

Comment: I said "a" solution, not "the" solution. I actually thought once you're compositing this might help out a lot, bc. you don't have to re-render when the head is slightly too concealed by the reflections. The other thing could quite likely be a bug, or a general shortcoming.